# Django-Userena: Overriding profile editing form

Tags: django, forms, url

This is my first time working with Userena, and I'm trying to override the profile edit form so it won't show mugshots or privacy settings. Here is my attempt so far (from this page http://tundebabzy.blogspot.com/2013/04/an-easy-way-to-override-third-party-app.html).

I created an app to intercept urls to `'accounts/user/edit'` by using the URL below:

```
url(r'^accounts/(?P<username>[\.\w-]+)/edit/$',{'edit_profile_form': CustomEditProfileForm,} ,name='userena_profile_edit')
```

The custom edit form:

```
class CustomEditProfileForm(userena_views.EditProfileForm):
""" Base form used for fields that are always required """

class Meta:
    model = get_profile_model()
    exclude = ['user', 'mugshot', 'privacy', 'first_name']
```

The custom view:

```
def profile_edit(request, username, edit_profile_form= forms.CustomEditProfileForm,
             template_name='userena/profile_form.html', success_url=None,
             extra_context=None, **kwargs):

return userena_views.profile_edit(request=request, username=username,
        edit_profile_form=edit_profile_form, template_name=template_name,
        success_url=success_url, extra_context=extra_context)
```

I can get to the edit form just fine from here, but the form still looks the same. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Userena base form should be imported from userena.forms and not from userena.views (maybe it's only a typo here):

```
from userena.forms import EditProfileForm
```

The `Meta` class is ok, but this way you're overriding it altogether. Generally I prefer to extend Meta classes like this:

```
class Meta(EditProfileForm.Meta):
  exclude = EditProfileForm.Meta.exclude + ['mugshot', 'privacy', 'first_name']
```

so there's no need to repeat what the base class is doing and it's less risky in case it changes in future releases.

Finally you don't need to create a custom view, but simply to specify your custom form inside the URL definition:

```
url(r'^accounts/(?P<username>[\.\w-]+)/edit/$',
   'userena.views.profile_edit',
   {'edit_profile_form': CustomEditProfileForm},
   name='userena_profile_edit'),
```

Note the second line `'userena.views.profile_edit'`, referencing the normal Userena view.